# SQL, import different columns from different tables into excel

Tags: sql, excel

I need to import data using "microsoft query wizard and odbc" into excel. However i need to import different columns from two different tables in the database. The "join" statement didn't work as there isn't a common column between the two tables. How do i edit this by writing SQL statements? The wizard guided me through different tables in the database, but i couldnt select the columns i need manually as well.

please help!

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you a way to do this, this may be a long procedure but first you have to install php-mysql and phpmyadmin....., a simple way to do this will be via xampp, wamp, lamp, mamp etc

you have export your tables in .sql format(i think that you can do)

then you have to login in phpmyadmin and create any random database.

after that you have to import those databases in mysql...,

If you done this successfully, now we are all set up to do what you want...,

step 1:- you have to run select query in phpmyadmin's SQL tab, selecting the coloumns and data whatever you want from diffrent tables

step2:- if your query is executed successfully you will see a table with you coloumns and nothing else and now you can scroll down to see a export button there just click it

step 3: you cal select either the csv(the excel format) or whatever you want, and there will be a checkbox of save file as(do not forget to chekk).

step 4: hit save or GO(i don't remember )

if you find any problem, please ask again